# The variable is not shown in the console log

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Could any one help me ? I am beginner to jquery and ajax . I am displaying the value in the console log ,,but nothing is shown . what may the problem be ?

script.php

```
<script src="/icac/ar/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#see").click(function() {

      val =  $(this).val();
       $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: 'var='+ val,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(val);
       $("#c").html(data);
    }
        });      
          });      

});
</script>
<div class="test">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="see" value="1">see</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <p>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="see"  value="2">see</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <p>cccccccccccccccccccccc</p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="see"  value="3">see</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <p>ddddddddddddddddddd</p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="see"  value="4">see</a>
</div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

test.php

```
<span class="ss"><?php
    if (isset($_POST["var"])){
     echo $_POST["var"]; }?>

</span>
```

Comment: I would guess your AJAX call doesn't enter your success. Try adding an error function.

Comment: First clean up your code, an `id` must be unique!

Comment: how to add an error function ? what do u mean unique

Comment: Ids need to be unique as they are used to identify something - how can you identify it if it is the same as other things. With that in mind, jQuery will only take the first item with an id it finds, this means that your click event only gets bound to the first anchor with the id see and not the others.  If you need to bind to multiple elements, use a class. Also value is not a valid attribute for an anchor, use a [data attribute](https://api.jquery.com/data/) instead

Comment: @NasrallaMohammad -unique  means you cannot use same id multiple time in same page.

Comment: @UMAR FAROOQUE KHAN  What is the correct ,easiet way , I don't need to make things complicated ,

Comment: @NasrallaMohammad -Use class in the place of id and if you want to get data, add attribute <a href="javascript:void(0);" some-data="1" id="see">see</a>. Get   var dat=  $(this).attr('some-data');

Answer (score 1):

1- An id must be unique and you cannot use value attribute in href.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#see").click(function (event) {
             event.preventDefault();
            var val = $(this).text();
            console.log(val);
                   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: 'var='+ val,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(val);
       $("#c").html(data);
    }
        }); 

        });

    });
</script>
<div class="test">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="see">see</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should't assign the same id to different html elements. Try setting a unique id for each element and targeting that or changing id="see" to class="see" (if you change to a class make sure to change you selector to '.see')

Answer (score 0):

HTML element anchor `<a>` you can not use value attribute, 
     instead of that you can use data-value attribute, on other hand use unique id as well

```
 var val =  $(this).attr('data-value');
 console.log(val)
```